# 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, subtype

Currently I'm learning Flutter and I have an error during the execution of a project that I can't find. Maybe someone has an idea where the error could be?

This is the error:

> [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

This is the function in which the error is located:

```
  Future<void> fetchAndSetProducts([bool filterByUser = false]) async {
final filterString = filterByUser ? 'orderBy="creatorId"&equalTo="$userId"' : '';
var url =
    'https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/products.json?auth=$authToken&$filterString';
try {
  final response = await http.get(url);
  final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  if (extractedData == null) {
    return;
  }
  url =
      'https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/userFavorites/$userId.json?auth=$authToken';
  final favoriteResponse = await http.get(url);
  final favoriteData = json.decode(favoriteResponse.body);
  final List<Product> loadedProducts = [];
  extractedData.forEach((prodId, prodData) {
    loadedProducts.add(Product(
      id: prodId,
      title: prodData['title'],
      description: prodData['description'],
      price: prodData['price'],
      isFavorite:
          favoriteData == null ? false : favoriteData[prodId] ?? false,
      imageUrl: prodData['imageUrl'],
    ));
  });
  _items = loadedProducts;
  notifyListeners();
} catch (error) {
  throw (error);
}
```

}

Comment: share `Product` class code

Comment: Could you please add the `Product` class code and the JSON you are retrieving from Firebase? I suspect the issue is in your `extractedData.forEach` method call.